# How to "check" certain checkboxes only using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a HTML form containing checkboxes in the form of ..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-1" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-2" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-3" value="3" /> 3 <br />
        ...
        ...
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-28" value="28" /> 28<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-29" value="29" /> 29<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="range[]" class="range_opts" id="range-30" value="30" /> 30<br />
```

With this JS Code I Select all or Deselect all checkboxes

```
$('#select_all_ranges').click(function() {
    $('input[name="range[]"]').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
    });
});
$('#deselect_all_ranges').click(function() {
    $('input[name="range[]"]').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

But I need the functionality where user would be able to have certain checkboxes selected, depending upon the input

```
    <input type="text" name="from_range" id="frm_range" />
   <input type="text" name="to_range" id="to_range" />
    <img src="icon.png" id="range123" />
```

so if user inputs from 5 to 20  and clicks on icon it checks checkboxes from 5-20.

Can you please help me some ideas how this can be achieved. I can alter markup to apply some classes/selecter ids etc if you suggest, if it would make it any easier. 
And I understand that this functionality is for users having javascript enabled browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't have to loop through all the checkboxes to check each one in your code. This would be a faster equivalent: $('input.range_opts').attr('checked', true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#range123").click(function() {
  var from = $("#frm_range").val();
  var to = $("#to_range").val();
  var expr = ":checkbox.range_opts:lt(" + to + ")";
  if (from > 1) {
    expr += ":gt(" + (from-1) + ")";
  }
  $(expr).attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: @cletus .. can you please help me know how do these gt and lt work? I mean do they compare agains "element id" value? Thanks

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index :gt() and :lt() work on the index into the set and start at 0. Say $("blah") returns 10 items. $("blah:gt(7)") will return the 9th and 10th item (7 on 0 index is the 8th item).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('#range123').click(function() {
    var bottom = $("#frm_range").value;
    var top = $("#to_range").value;
    $('input[name="range[]"]').each(function() {
            this.checked = ((this.value > bottom) && (this.value < top));
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, I had just finshed writing nearly same. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply check the [index](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index) while selecting the checkboxes:

```
$('#select_all_ranges').click(function() {
    var from = $('#frm_range').val();
    var to = $('#to_range').val();
    var expr = '.range_opts:gt(' + (from-2) + '):lt(' + (to-1) + ')';
    $(expr).attr("checked", true);
});
```